# SCA authentication while update subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

i want to implement `SCA` in my project.i would like to know whether `SCA` forces the user to complete 2 factor authentication while  update,cancel,resume subscription.so i can handle the code accordingly.so far stripe didn't ask me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SDA comes into play for authenticating online card payments. Stripe Billing has been updated to support SCA requirements.

You won't necessarily need to authenticate for all subscription changes (such as cancel or update) but you could for scenarios like a subscription signup, a card change on a subscription, or on a recurring charge on a subscription.

The following link describes the scenarios and tools you would leverage for Stripe Billing + SCA: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#upgrading-integration